# Em uma estrutura repetitiva há diferenças entre trabalhar com Object ou Array?

Tags: php, mysql, array, tipagem

Quando faço uma consulta na base de dados por PHP e quero retornar esses dados com `while`, geralmente uso o `fetch_object()`, que retorna os dados em tipo **objeto**.

Por exemplo:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABELA";
$exect = $conn->query($query);

while($row = $exect->fetch_object()){
    echo $row->coluna.'<br>';
}
```

Mas antes eu usava `fetch_array()` para retorno de dados.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABELA";
$exect = $conn->query($query);

while($row = $exect->fetch_array()){
    echo $row['coluna'].'<br>';
}
```

Nesses dois casos surgem alguns questionamentos:

1 - Tem diferença de performance?

2 - Tem diferença de usabilidade?

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com usabilidade?

Comment: Usar com facilidade o objeto ou item do array em métodos, funções... então, não sei. KKK

Comment: Acho que você quis dizer **legibilidade** não?

Comment: Faz parte também.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124240/mysql-results-in-php-arrays-or-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essencialmente a diferença está no tipo de dados que será retornado mesmo. Use o que for mais conveniente para o seu estilo ou necessidade.

O [`fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) retornará obviamente um *array* que poderá ser acessado por índice ou nome dos campos (chaves) ou ainda pelo dois. Isto é definido no parâmetro `resulttype` e padrão é o acesso por ambas as formas.

O `fetch_object` poderá ser acessado com a sintaxe de acesso de membros de um objeto. Ele pode popular um objeto de uma classe específica. Pode ser passado como parâmetro.

Em termos de performance são essencialmente equivalentes, porque não existem objetos de fato em PHP, eles são *arrays* associativos por de baixo dos panos. Como é uma camada de abstração extra é provável que seja ligeiramente mais lento, mas a diferença será ínfima.

Evidentemente pode haver outros problemas com o `fetch_object`, afinal ele converterá o conteúdo da chave para um identificador do PHP. Há regras do que pode estar contido nos identificadores. O que acontece se tiver algum caractere impróprio para o PHP no nome do campo do banco de dados? Tem que se proteger disto com `{}` e a sintaxe fica pior.

Se quiser automatizar o acesso dos membros através de variáveis também terá que usar este recurso nos objetos. É mais natural usar o *array* que trabalha melhor com variáveis para indicar a chave/índice a ser acessado. Este é um padrão muito comum de quem sabe fazer códigos otimizados, seguem o [princípio DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e gosta de fazer a linguagem trabalhar pra ele e não ele trabalhar pra linguagem.

Algumas pessoas acham que transformar tudo em objeto é mais fácil de trabalhar, mas elas não sabem que no fundo não estão acrescentando vantagem alguma, nem de performance, nem de organização, nada, é só gosto. Então escolha um ou outro pelo gosto.