# O DRY é para evitar redundâncias, certo?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação, princípios-de-programação

O [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) significa Don't Repeat Yourself. Então toda vez que eu ver uma repetição no código não estou fazendo DRY? O DRY é sobre não ter redundâncias? Como ele deve ser aplicado?

Comment: Resolvi postar este par de pergunta e resposta porque a pergunta já feita sobre o assunto era ampla e tinha respostas que não respondiam totalmente o que foi perguntado e feito de forma muito burocrática e que eu achei equivocada em alguns pontos. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/101

Answer (score 81, accepted):

## Redundância X Don't Repeat Yourself

Isto é repetição:

```
valorDoProdutoComprado = valorDoProdutoComprado + 1
```

Em muitas linguagens poderia ser assim:

```
valorDoProdutoComprado++
```

Isso é DRY?

Isto:

```
meuObjeto.propriedade1 = 0
meuObjeto.propriedade2 = ""
meuObjeto.propriedade3 = true
```

Em algumas linguagens poderia ser escrito assim:

```
with meuObjeto
    .propriedade1 = 0
    .propriedade2 = ""
    .propriedade3 = true
```

Agora fiz DRY?

Pois bem, redundância é ruim? Então o abaixo é ótimo?

```
if valor == 0
    fazALgumaCoisa()
fazOutraCoisa()
```

Ou a redundância pode ajudar?

```
if valor == 0 {
    fazALgumaCoisa();
}
fazOutraCoisa();
```

Isto:

```
UmaClasse obj = new UmaClasse();
```

É o mesmo que isto sem a redundância/repetição?

```
var obj = new UmaClasse()
```

Note que o primeiro impõe um contrato para a variável, ela precisa ser daquele tipo. O segundo indica que o tipo não importa e o que for atribuído para a variável está bom. Há diferença semântica ainda que o resultado possa ser o mesmo.

**Repetir ou redundar código não é o problema**, claro que há redundâncias indesejáveis:

```
if ok == true
```

E **há redundâncias problemáticas**, essas são as que devem ser observadas para o DRY.

Se você faz um código simples ou complexo que só vá ser usado uma vez, obviamente não estará violando o DRY, certo?

Não é tão simples. Isso é verdade estritamente, até que um dia alguém precisa dele em outro lugar e o que era único deixa de ser, só que quem precisou daquilo não sabia que já tinha pronto em um lugar. Tem que pensar na extensibilidade para fazer DRY.

Pegue este código (não faz mais nada com `z`, mas poderia um dia fazer):

```
z = x + y
print z
```

e

```
print x + y
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Dry.ptg).

Qual é mais DRY?

Há controvérsias.

## Definição formal

A [informação "oficial"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pragmatic_Programmer) do que é DRY é:

> Cada parte do conhecimento deve ter uma representação única, não ambígua e definitiva dentro do sistema.

O DRY tem a ver com [*canonicidade*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form). Você não pode ter a mesma informação em mais de um lugar da aplicação ou mesmo da solução como um todo.

O DRY é sobre ter uma regra em um único lugar ([cânone](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%C3%A2none)). Imagina que você coloca a regra em dois lugares (lembrando que códigos são regras que o programador estabelece para o computador executar). Uma hora você precisa mudar a regra, vai lembrar/saber que precisa mudar nos dois? A mudança manterá as duas fazendo a mesma coisa?

A canonicidade pode ocorrer dentro de uma função, dentro de um módulo (classe, por exemplo), dentro de uma aplicação (um executável, por exemplo) ou uma solução, incluindo aí partes que não sejam código (documentação, por exemplo).

Ter um **único ponto de mudança** de um fato é primordial para **facilitar a manutenção**.

O melhor [debate sobre o assunto](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) (ainda que se apeguem à coisas bobas como ter o protótipo de funções C ser anti-DRY ou não) provavelmente está na Wiki C2. Destaco especialmente a introdução:

> A duplicação (seja ela acidental ou proposital) pode levar a pesadelos de manutenção, além de atrapalhar a refatoração e gerar contradições lógicas.
>
> A duplicação e a possibilidade de contradições podem surgir em qualquer lugar: na arquitetura, em requisitos, código ou documentação. Os efeitos podem variar desde falhas de implementação de código, à confusão dos desenvolveres; até a falha completa do sistema.
>
> Pode-se argumentar que a maior dificuldade na remediação do problema do Ano 2000, veio da falta de uma simples abstração de datas dentro de um sistema; o conhecimento das datas e o seu tratamento eram espalhados por muitas partes.

## Como tornar o código mais canônico

Muitos vão pensar na *canonicidade* dentro da função como forma de eliminar repetição, mas não é isso, é sobre a regra. Quase sempre um trecho de código só pode ser canônico criando uma nova função com esse código devidamente preparado para funcionar em qualquer situação. Esse código apenas responderá com a regra da forma mais simples possível, mantendo, claro, a [responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101).

Onde esta função será colocada é uma questão importante também:

- Pode estar dentro da função que vai usá-la (se a linguagem assim permitir);
- dentro da mesma classe;
- mesmo pacote (seja lá como a linguagem trabalhe com pacotes);
- mesmo executável/*script*;
- pode até estar acessível externamente, por um *webservice*, por exemplo.

A regra pode ser tão simples quanto pegar um valor de uma variável/constante global, ou quanto fazer cálculos complexos pegando dados de um db ou de um site.

#### Abstração

Isso tem a ver também com abstração. Você pode se perguntar que se é para pegar uma variável global, por que eu não pego logo a variável em vez de criar um camada extra? Depende da situação, se a regra é pegar **esta** variável específica, não precisa fazer mais nada, já está canônico. Se esta variável é um detalhe de implementação, então a regra é pegar uma informação, e de onde ela vem é detalhe, então precisa de uma abstração para deixar canônico.

Quando usa uma função `pegaEndereçoPeloCep("01234-567)` não interessa se a consulta é feita em um banco de dados, no site dos Correios ou outro lugar. Se você não tiver uma função para isto fica fácil perder a canonicidade.

Em quase todos os códigos legados que trabalhei e na maioria dos códigos em perguntas aqui no SOpt que tenham mais que um trecho muito curto eu vejo coisas do tipo:

```
valorDescontado = valorTotal * (desconto / 100)
```

Simples, né? Isso será espalhando por todo o código, ou por ^C ^V ou por ser tão intuitivo que vai criando na mão. E se a forma do desconto mudar? Se tiver uma condição nova? Se o valor do desconto passar ser pego de uma tabela? Se por alguma razão ele não for mais uma porcentagem simples?

#### Ferramentas

A ferramenta mais óbvia para fazer o código mais DRY é a função. OOP, serviços (web, bancos com *stored procedures*, etc.) são outras. [Dicionário de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/347190/101) e técnicas de [*scaffolding*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119731/101) também ajudam evitar ter código redundante, principalmente em tecnologias diferentes.

Usar ferramentas para duplicar o código de forma automática **não** viola o DRY. Não estamos falando de código curto e sim de código com boa manutenibilidade.

Esse é um dos motivos de muitas pessoas preferirem ter código em *stored procedure*. É uma forma de dar *canonicidade* para uma solução de várias aplicações. Existem outras soluções que obtém o mesmo de forma melhor, mas isso é outro assunto.

#### Técnicas específicas

MVC é hoje uma técnica exageradamente empregada e que "incentiva" violar o DRY. Parte da violação ocorre por falta de entendimento do MVC e não saber onde colocar cada informação. Parte é pelo desconhecimento de como resolver problemas reais que causam duplicação. MVC mal empregado causa mais problemas que soluções, mas a pessoa acha que fazer o mesmo que todo mundo está fazendo não tem como errar. Dá vontade de chorar vendo os MVCs por aí.

Se é pra criar mais de um ponto de mudança, não faça MVC!

Há casos que o problema exige uma certa flexibilização, permitindo que a aplicação possa ter comportamentos diferentes. Nenhum problema com o DRY. Padrões de projeto podem ser aplicados para que a flexibilização seja obtida sem ter a mesma regra em locais diferentes. Ter várias regras não é problema, ter a mesma em dois lugares diferentes é o problema.

Sabe aquele negócio de não usar [números mágicos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants)? Isso é DRY.

[Normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) é uma forma de DRY.

Redundâncias que tornam o código melhor não violam o DRY.

Por isso eu uso [dicionários de dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dictionary) de forma estendida (não só na definição clássica) há muitos anos. No dicionário da aplicação tenho todos os fatos da aplicação em um só lugar. Mudando ali, estou mudando em tudo o que preciso. Dependendo da tecnologia usada até o código pode estar nesse dicionário, mas na maioria das linguagens não dá para fazer isto. Aí existem técnicas específicas para ligar os fatos com o código.

Como sempre, é claro que não é para usar certas técnicas em certos tipos de aplicação.

## DRY soluciona o quê?

Alguns ainda podem estar pensando que DRY é para reduzir digitação. Ou pelo menos ganhar tempo de manutenção. Até é no último caso, mas não porque tem menos código por si só (ainda que menos código sempre ajude alguma coisa). A redução no tempo de manutenção é não ter que ficar caçando as redundâncias, fazer tranquilamente uma mudança sabendo que tudo continuará consistente, sem ter que arrumar erros que nem imagina que acontecerá quando mudar algo.

DRY exige que qualquer **informação de código** seja única. DRY cria uma fonte autoritativa de como deve ser um comportamento.

Feito corretamente [aumenta a coesão e diminui o acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101). Feito errado...

DRY ajuda ter responsabilidade única. Tentar amontoar as coisas em uma função só para evitar repetição só piora o [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Por isso é que é importante distinguir DRY de eliminação de repetição.

DRY concretamente evita pesadelos de manutenção. Mais abstratamente exige que o programador pense no que está fazendo, porque ele está colocando aquele código ali e se pode fazer de outra forma para uso futuro. DRY é planejamento.

## Exageros

É óbvio que pode haver exageros. Hoje é muito comum fazer aplicações em camadas, inclusive usando tecnologias bem heterogêneas.

Um exemplo típico é a aplicação web. Frequentemente usamos mais de uma linguagem nesse tipo de ambiente. Se você tem Java de um lado e JavaScript do outro, provavelmente, pelo menos as mesmas validações terão que estar em dois lugares, já que precisa de duas linguagens. Algumas soluções que vejo por aí: "vamos fazer tudo em JS, assim dá pra aproveitar tudo", ou "todas validações serão feitas no servidor".

É o mesmo problema quando a pessoa acha que a solução é jogar tudo no banco de dados. A não ser que ela esteja pensando em um dicionário de dados e saiba bem o que está fazendo (que precisam de código na aplicação para sua perfeita realização), não costuma funcionar tão bem quanto o esperado, exagerando o acesso ao banco de dados.

Este é um caso para usar ferramentas que façam conversões ou gerações de código, ou aceitar que alguma duplicação terá que existir de forma muito bem documentada.

Também tem que tomar cuidado com as abstrações erradas. Um dos motivos de ter escrito isso é que muitas pessoas vão querer usar DRY para evitar repetição. Existe repetição intencional, consciente. Isso ocorre quando os conceitos são diferentes mas momentaneamente usam o mesmo código (mesmo que dure para semrpe). Não use DRY nesses casos, vai ter problemas no futuro.

#### DRY pode tornar o código pior

Também é preciso cuidado para não criar uma repetição para eliminar outra. Ou piorar a legibilidade em nome do DRY. É raro, mas é possível piorar o código fazendo o DRY.

O DRY pode trazer complexidade em alguns códigos quando em exagero, mas muitas vezes a complexidade de fato ocorre por requisitos complexos ou pelo uso conjunto de outras técnicas que tornam o código exageradamente complexo. Por isso que eu costumo preferir o DRY se ele conflitar com outro princípio. Ficar se repetindo para simplificar não costuma ser a solução. Se o código ficaria muito complexo, automatize a repetição e está fazendo DRY.

Não precisa nem dizer que pode-se exagerar ao criar variáveis onde não precisa, como mostrado no último exemplo da seção inicial desta resposta. Não vai, por exemplo, criar uma variável `$p = "<p>"` para usar na montagem de um texto HTML em vez do literal direto.

Se um código é coincidentemente igual, mas não tem relação com outro, não vá aplicar DRY. Os projetos terão novos requerimentos. Pense como isso será afetado quando for fazer DRY. Na maior parte dos casos haverá ganho, mas nem sempre.

Além disto abstrações que produzem efeitos colaterais são bem ruins. Algo a ser evitado, pra não dizer proibido.

E existe casos em que tentar fazer DRY pode reduzir a legibilidade de tal forma que não compense seu uso. Uma abstração esconde o real mecanismo, é raro, mas nem sempre é o que queremos.

E lembre-se do [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). O que é simples depende de **contexto**. Simples não é sempre o mais curto, o menos repetido, mas frequentemente é. Portanto não crie uma abstração gratuitamente.

## Comentários e outros pontos do software

De acordo com os proponentes DRY não é só sobre o código, é também sobre a base de dados, os testes, a documentação, incluindo comentários.

De que adianta deixar todo o código canônico e outras partes permitirem uma ruptura por não estarem sincronizados.

Algumas pessoas consideram os comentários como uma das piores formas de violar o DRY. De fato dependendo do comentário é mesmo ruim, não sei se tão ruim, porque ele não afeta o código, mas pode induzir o programador a erro. Umas das causas do uso jocoso do termo [WET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/363051) (*Write Everything Twice*).

O banco de dados deve ser manipulado pela solução como um todo de forma automática.

Os *builds* e até mesmo os *deploies* devem ser automatizados e providenciar partes da solução que são propositalmente faltantes durante o desenvolvimento para evitar a repetição.

Não exagere na documentação, mas o que fizer não pode sair de sincronia com o código real. Como fazer isto automaticamente?

## Conclusão ou TL; DR atrasado

DRY é sobre ter uma forma única de tratar determinada ação em uma solução de software. É ter em um só local todo o conhecimento que precisa sobre um assunto bem específico da solução. Mesmo que este local dependa de outras coisas.

É um reducionismo dizer que DRY é evitar duplicação de código.

Minha opinião é que DRY é o princípio mais importante da computação. Se o programador seguir ele corretamente, não importa a ferramenta, o paradigma, a tecnologia, a metodologia que usa, já estará fortemente no caminho certo. Se errar, pode escolher o que quiser, você tem lixo nas mãos. Não é OOP, Java, Agile, MVC, *design patterns*, camadas, etc. que vão te salvar. Vejo muita gente evitar o DRY em nome de outras coisas que trazem bem menos vantagens.

Além da técnica quando se escreve código, precisa de automação, automação, automação.

Claro que não é panaceia, não cura todos os males, não dispensa outras técnicas e fazer certo nem sempre é fácil ou possível. Se vira dogma religioso, como costuma acontecer com muita coisa na computação, pode ter efeito contrário. Cuidado pra não transformá-lo em "boa prática".

Eu sou um proponente radical do DRY e ainda assim não faço em tudo.

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (a definição inicial é um pouco perigosa)
- [Entrevista dos principais proponentes](http://www.artima.com/intv/dry.html)

Comment: "Se um código é coincidentemente igual, mas não tem relação com outro, não vá aplicar DRY.". Para mim esse é o ponto mais difícil de acertar. O pessoal acaba abstraindo classes ou criando funções para encapsular o comportamento de dois componentes que a princípio são parecidos, mas que evoluem separadamente.

Comment: "Note que o primeiro impõe um contrato para a variável, ela precisa ser daquele tipo. O segundo indica que o tipo não importa e o que for atribuído para a variável está bom. Há diferença semântica ainda que o resultado seja o mesmo." Depende... i) Um contrato que é atendido *na mesma linha de código* me parece um contrato meio inútil; ii) IDEs modernas e ferramentas de refatoração irão alterar os dois lados da atribuição; iii) `var` da forma como é presente em linguagens estáticas como Scala, Kotlin, C# não tem a diferença semântica citada: a variável é, de fato, do mesmo tipo da expressão.

Comment: i) você pode ter a opinião que quiser, mas todo mundo que gosta de códigos legíveis sabe quando explicitar um contrato.; ii) Pode haver uma cascata de modificações inclusive na API pública que a quebraria; iii) `var` evita apenas a redigitação, se é DRY ou não, depende de como está sendo usado, e novamente depende da necessidade de explicitar o contrato ou não. Quando usar `var` está dando uma semântica para o código. Reforço que DRY não é sobre redundância, é sobre semântica. Veja também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101

Comment: Apesar das referências úteis apresentadas, ficou estranho começar o artigo com tantos exemplos que não tem nada haver com o que foi perguntado. Sugiro deixar apenas a parte mais textual.

Comment: @ramaral acho que está errado mesmo :D Vou ver melhor antes de mudar

Comment: Infelizmente quando se trata de front-end muitas vezes usar DRY é um tiro no pé, querer reutilizar css, html, jsp, se não for com um bom framework (angular, react, etc), só causa problemas, tentando atingir DRY muitos caem no pecado do uso excessivo de Templates, excesso de váriáveis e funções javascript. Por fim, muitas vezes é melhor copiar e colar.

Answer (score 9):

Olha, DRY é um principio filosófico sobre evitar duplicação de lógica aqui e acolá. Existem muitas discussões sobre o que é duplicação ou não e até onde é válido evitar duplicação, inclusive. Não dá pra assumir uma postura extremista do tipo "agora eu sou DRY". Sempre é bom analisar teu contexto e possibilidades.

Para aplicar esse principio e filosofia de forma consistente e consciente, é preciso ser mestre em outros assuntos, como:

1. Structured programming
2. Aspect Oriented Programming
3. Component Oriented Programming
4. Domain Driven Design
5. Design Patterns

São estratégias pra você usar e eliminar redundância de código. Bom, uma simples criação de subrotinas também já ajuda muito.

Aí você pergunta, como aplicar?

1. Desenvolva **senso crítico**. Toda vez que você concluir o desenvolvimento de uma atividade, pergunte-se, "como eu posso melhorar o que eu fiz?"
   Daí você analisa tudo o que fez e vai eliminando redundâncias.
2. Faça **revisão conceitual**, continuamente. Pra entender como evitar redundâncias, você precisa saber fazer a eliminação da redundância em si. Por exemplo, como evitar redundância aplicando Design Patterns? Veja que Design Patterns tem 3 subgrupos de padrões. Padrões de criação, padrões estruturais e comportamentais. São 23 padrões no total. Será que seu código consegue ficar mais simples se você alterar a sua estrutura? Tenho certeza que pelo menos 3 padrões podem ser aplicados de forma tácita, diária e rotineira. No meu coração, estão:

   1 Template Method 
   2 Strategy 
   3 Facade 
   4 Decorator 
   5 Factory Method 
   6 Visitor

Hoje, eu consigo olhar uma situação e dizer com qual padrão consigo resolvê-la. Mas até chegar nesse nível, eu tive que criticar meus projetos e provocar alterações aplicando padrões.

3. Embarque no mundo da **refatoração de código**. Tem muita literatura sobre refatoração. E dar uma lida sobre refatoração vai te jogar na experiência de práticas de melhorias. O Martin Fowler pode ser sua primeira referência. Ele coautor de livros como [Refactoring to Patterns](https://www.amazon.com.br/Refactoring-Patterns-Addison-Wesley-Signature-English-ebook/dp/B001TKD4RQ?tag=goog0ef-20&smid=A18CNA8NWQSYHH&ascsubtag=go_1366271959_70721127517_351260994638_aud-519888259198:pla-750106166283_c_) e [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](https://www.amazon.com.br/Refactoring-Improving-Existing-Addison-Wesley-Signature-ebook/dp/B07LCM8RG2?tag=goog0ef-20&smid=A18CNA8NWQSYHH&ascsubtag=go_1366271959_70721127517_351260994638_aud-519888259198:pla-750106166283_c_). Bom, existem outros autores pra você aprender e quanto mais você tiver acesso a pessoas diferentes dando visões diferentes sobre o mesmo assunto melhor.
4. Utilize alguma ferramenta de refatoração. Geralmente elas apontam duplicação de código, malfeitorias e descuidos. A exemplo, Resharper é muito poderoso.

Answer (score 2):

Voltando lá na pergunta inicial, acho importante não confundir repetibilidade com redundância. São conceitos diferentes.

Com base em toda a detalhada e completa explicação que o Maniero nos presentou acima, eu entendo que DRY é um princípio criado para evitar repetibilidade de código, o que facilita a manutenção dele. O ponto de maior importância para mim é: se eu tenho um mesmo trecho de código ocorrendo múltiplas vezes no mesmo projeto e porventura precisar revisá-lo, será que lembrarei de fazer as alterações necessárias em todas as ocorrências dele? Há um risco elevado de, durante essa revisão, eu acabar inserindo um bug no programa que antes não existia.

**Repetibilidade não é redundância**

Em um contexto técnico, redundância é uma forma de garantir que um determinado recurso ou serviço não fique indisponível, fazendo com que esse recurso ou serviço possa ser consumido de maneira ininterrupta.

**Exemplo 1:** alguns switches de rede mais robustos muitas vezes possuem duas entradas independentes de fonte de alimentação. Caso uma fonte falhe, o switch continua operacional porque existe uma segunda fonte alimentando ele.

**Exemplo 2:** existem protocolos de roteamento dinâmico (como o OSPF) que monitoram constantemente o estado das rotas de uma rede para que, no caso de indisponibilidade de uma determinada rota, as tabelas de roteamento dos roteadores (ou switches de camada 3) sejam atualizadas com uma rota alternativa, garantindo que não haja perda de comunicação por conta da rota que ficou indisponível.

Redundância nem sempre garante que um determinado recurso ou serviço fique 100% do tempo disponível (isso é muito difícil de se conseguir - e consequentemente caro), mas sempre consegue aumentar consideravelmente sua disponibilidade.

Código repetido não proporciona redundância, mas sim insere o problema da repetibilidade no projeto.